# Could not open directory '.dbus/': Permission denied

Tags: command-line, permissions, zsh

I'm working on `Ubuntu 18.04.01` using `Guake` terminal and `zsh`.

Every time I run a command in terminal I get this warning after executing this command.

```
Could not open directory '.dbus/': Permission denied
```

I noticed having this warning after installing `zsh`.

- What does it mean?
- How can I solve this warning?

Comment: what is the output of `ls -ld ~/.dbus/`? who is the owner of the folder?

Comment: drwx------ 3 root root 4096

Comment: Find all those cases on your $HOME with `find ~ -user root`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like your `~/.dbus/` folder is owned by `root` instead of by your own user.

If this is the case, you can:

1. Remove that folder, using:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf ~/.dbus
   ```

Or:

2. Change the ownership to your-username / your-user-group using:

   ```
   sudo chown -R your-user-name.your-user-group-name ~/.dbus/
   ```

   Note: replace `your-user-name.your-user-group-name` with the actual values, e.g. if your user is `sal` and your group is also `sal` than it will be: `sal.sal`

As @Pablo Bianchi added in the comments below, `$USER` environment variable holds your-user-name (and in Ubuntu your-group-name is usually equal to your username) hence in most cases you can run the following command:

```
    sudo chown -R $USER.$USER ~/.dbus/
```

More info regarding Ubuntu environment variables can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what is this directory for? Is it safe to just delete it?

Comment: Probably just `$USER.$USER` for your username:group

Comment: @PabloBianchi - thanks for your comment! added the info to my answer